# "svn: E175012: Connection timed out" when I compile my first Shogun program

Tags: http, svn, vpn, shogun

I am new Shogun user,besides, this is my first time to use SVN.(I think the problem is SVN not Shogun)
those are the environment what I use:

- Windows 10
- Shogun 4.0.0
- TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3;
- VisualSVN-5.1.3;
- VisualSVN-Server-3.5.1-x64;
- VS 2013

Now I am in trouble when I want to get started an simple example of Shogun(copy in Documentation) as follow:

```
#include <shogun/base/init.h>
using namespace shogun;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    init_shogun();
    exit_shogun();
    return 0;
}
```

then, I try to compile it in Vs 2013, it tell me:

```
1>  Generating version header
3>  Building Custom Rule E:/shogun/CMakeLists.txt
3>  CMake does not need to re-run because E:\shogun-configure\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
3>  Creating directories for 'MSIntTypes'
3>  Performing download step (SVN checkout) for 'MSIntTypes'
3>  svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ' http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk '
3>  svn: E175012: Connection timed out
3>  C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: 
"cmd.exe" has exited. code is 1.
```

Then, I considerd that maybe some problems with SVN, I try to checkout some respositories:
At first, I try to checkout an respositories what I create myself:'_http://burningbear:8443/!/#new_rep', it can be checkout normally.
**Then I try to chekout the respository:'_http ://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk', but the Tortoise just not responding for a long time, then it reply me that:**

```
 Command: Checkout from _http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included  
 Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL  
 Error:  '_http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'  
 Error: Error running context: 你的主机中的软件中止了一个已建立的连接。(what I use is Chinese,it means "the software in your host stop an connected connection")
```

**In China, We can not access googlecode unless we use VPN, so I change the server, to enable Proxy Server, the following is my setting:**

```
  Server address: 127.0.0.1  
  Port: 8087
```

Then I try to checkout again as:

When I check out _http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

```
 Checkout from _http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
 Unable to connect to a repository at URL'_http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
 The HTTP method 'OPTIONS' is not allowed on '/svn/trunk'
```

When I update the repositories what I have checkout before(URL is :_http://burningbear:8443/!/#new_rep). It move slowly, I spend about half hour, SVN tell me: "**2 kBytes transferred in 20 minutes and 2 seconds**"

```
  Command: Update  
  Updating: E:\test2  
  Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://burningbear:8443/svn/new_rep'  
  Error: Connection timed out  
  Completed!:
```

Now, I don't know what's the problem. It take me several days and I still can not solve it. Please help me! Thank you in advanced!
(I can not post more than 2 links now, so all of URL above I add an '_' mark before 'http')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Currently there's no way to compile natively shogun on Windows unfortunately. Although your problem seems to be unrelated, and it fails with svn, which is weird because the official repo of the shogun is using `git`: http://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/</s>

<s>worked on the weekend on the native Windows support of shogun, you can find it in the `feature/windows` branch of the official repository: https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/tree/feature/windows</s>

**UPDATE**: the feature branch has been merged into develop branch. from now on shogun can be compiled on windows natively.

Answer (score 0):

Google Code is not available anymore: `http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk`. That's why the tool fails to access `googlecode.com`.